# i want to return json type in php

Tags: php, json

i'm really beginner in php.

When i return json type in php,  i have some trouble like below img.

[image: my issue img]

"0" is disappeared.

My code...

```
    $rank = 1;
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $row = array($r["national_id"] => (string)$rank);
            array_push($data, $row);
            $rank++;
        }
        echo encode($data);
    } else {
        echo "Failed messge from server: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
```

I have to do like {"0": "2"}
What should i do for this? help me~

Comment: used json_encode() function to do like this : echo json_encode($data)

Comment: i have customized json_encode().
function encode($val) {
 return json_encode($val, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}

Comment: i think hint is '"0"'...

Answer (score 3):

In order to encode a given Array in PHP, you need to use the function

```
json_encode(value, options, depth)
```

with *options* and *depth* being optional.
In your case, this will do the work:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

[Link to the PHP documentation here:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: thanks for your comment. i have used customized json_encode()... function encode($val) { return json_encode($val, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); } so, i think this is not a key for solving my error ..